# Spring uses varchar with @Nationalized annotation if the value is null

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, always-encrypted

I have just updated my Spring Boot project from 2.1.7.RELEASE to 2.7.10. I use SQL Server database where some of columns encrypted using Always Encrypted (via Java Keystore).

Before the update everthing went well. After the update there is an error.

There is a form with these fields: A [nullable], B, C. All of them are strings and A is encrypted in the database and it has a `org.hibernate.annotations.Nationalized` annotation.
And there is a query the corresponding repository: existsByAAndBAndC. This query fails if A is null but success if A is not null.

Under the hood in the JDBC sp_describe_parameter_encryption call fails with the following error:

```
The data types nvarchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'xxx', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'yyy') and varchar(1) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'xxx', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'yy') collation_name = 'zzz' are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

At this point Spring/Hibernate/JDBC converts this filed into `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`. If the A is not null then it converts to nvarchar and the repo call is success.

Is there any idea?

I have tried number of other versions of Spring Boot, tried `@Type` annotation also. I expect some other tipps.

Comment: It might be a driver bug, do you use the latest jdbc ms driver?

Comment: I don't think so. I have tried the latest version and I also tried the version from the Spring Boot parent pom's dependencyManagement section.

Comment: Can you post the query and param string that is passed to sp_describe_parameter_encryption ?

Comment: Sure! This is the final query string of that call (if the A is null): `exec sp_describe_parameter_encryption
  N'select entity0.id from entity entity0 where entity0.A=@P0 and entity0.B=@P1 and entity0.C=@P2',
  N'@P0 varchar(1),@P1 nvarchar(2),@P2 varchar(6)'
 `
Now the problem is the @P0, because it's type is varchar(1) not a nvarchar.

Comment: Hmm, but this is an error anyway, because `anything = NULL` will never evaluate to true

Comment: Yes, maybe the generated statement is also wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: Check that your column definitions in the entity class explicitly specify the correct SQL data type.  @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(255)")
private String A;

Comment: I have tried the `columnDefinition ` but it didn't work. The JavaDoc of this field says: `(Optional) The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column.`
According to the previous comment the framework doesn't use this setting, because select is not a DDL.